# How can I best clearly differentiate 3 screens with (almost) identical content?

Tags: forms, app

I just got approached with an app that has 3 screens, that almost do the same and have very similar content. So, we want to avoid someone entering into screen A when was supposed to be on screen B. The challenge is just that these screens look so similar.

So, currently, one screen is totally green, the other totally red and the 3rd is blue.
It's an aesthetic nightmare.

What other tools do we have at hand that we can use to clearly communicate to the user that s/he is on the correct of those screens?

Comment: Color is not the only visual contrast, there are several ways to show the differences between screens. Any mockup to share?

Comment: Instead of making whole screen colored, make heading with different color.

Answer (score 2):

If these three screens almost do the same and have very similar content I would argue that they need to be united into a single screen with a control that highlights the difference and forces the user to make an explicit decision, like a button or an accordion or even a set of tabs (although that's probably the least favorable option because one of the tabs is selected by default).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a combination of banner-backgrounds (or even just trim elements) which are colored differently, plus a visual element such as a graphic icon that represents the differentiated purpose accompanying the most prominent visual indicator (i.e. header).